# not sending information with mail form?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, email

i'm currently working on a site...
and i have encountered a error...

i'm using this mail form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// hide messages 
$("#error").hide();
$("#sent-form-msg").hide();

// on submit...
$("#contactForm #submit").click(function() {
    $("#error").hide();

    //required:

    //name
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    if(name == ""){
        $("#error").fadeIn().text("Name required.");
        $("input#name").focus();
        return false;
    }

    // email
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    if(email == ""){
        $("#error").fadeIn().text("Email required");
        $("input#email").focus();
        return false;
    }

    // web
    var web = $("input#web").val();
    if(web == ""){
        $("#error").fadeIn().text("Web required");
        $("input#web").focus();
        return false;
    }

    // comments
    var comments = $("#comments").val();

    // send mail php
    var sendMailUrl = $("#sendMailUrl").val();

    //to, from & subject
    var to = $("#to").val();
    var from = $("#from").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();

    // data string
    var dataString = 'name='+ name
                    + '&email=' + email        
                    + '&web=' + web
                    + '&comments=' + comments
                    + '&to=' + to
                    + '&from=' + from
                    + '&subject=' + subject;                                 
    // ajax
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: sendMailUrl,
        data: dataString,
        success: success()
    });
});  


// on success...
 function success(){
    $("#sent-form-msg").fadeIn();
    $("#contactForm").fadeOut();
 }

return false;
});
```

and i have this on my page: to gather the information and forward it to ma email adress.

```
<!-- form -->
            <form id="contactForm" action="#" method="post" />
                <fieldset>

                    <p>
                        <label for="name">Naam</label>
                        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your full name" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your email address" />
                    </p>


                    <p>
                        <label for="comments">Bericht</label>
                        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="20" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your comments"></textarea>
                    </p>

                    <!-- send mail configuration -->
                    <input type="hidden" value="kai.zaper@gmail.com" name="to" id="to" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="Jebike EmailForm mail" name="subject" id="subject" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="send-mail.php" name="sendMailUrl" id="sendMailUrl" />
                    <!-- ENDS send mail configuration -->

                    <p><input type="button" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" /> <span id="error" class="warning">Oeps, er is iets fout gegaan, probeer opnieuw.</span></p>
                </fieldset>

            </form>
            <p id="sent-form-msg" class="success">Uw email is verzonden.</p>
            <!-- ENDS form -->
```

But it isn't sending any emails. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems conflicting with `$` and `jQuery`.

Declare `$.noConflict();`

### Example:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

   // hide messages 
   $("#error").hide();
   ...
   ...
   ...
});
```

**OR**

Use either this way

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // hide messages 
    jQuery("#error").hide();
    ...
    ...
    ...
});
```

Or this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // hide messages 
    $("#error").hide();
    ...
    ...
    ...
});
```

Refer the document about **[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to check is your data actually being sent to your php like this (just uncomment sucess function and delete current one... ):

```
  $.ajax({
  type:"POST", //php method
  url:'process.php',//where to send data...
  cache:'false',//IE FIX
  data: data,

 //check is data sent successfuly to your process.php
 //success:function(response){
 //alert(response)
 //}

success: function(){ //on success do something...

$('.success').delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);

//alert('THX for your mail!');
} //end sucess 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess. I'm not a real coding expert, the site is a theme called Halftone. I have checked all the folders. And i haven't found any php files.

Comment: You need some PHP script to send your mails check this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/ Easy to use and works like a charm! I use it often in my projects:)

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the button's type 'button' to 'submit'.